# Update Gui without pressing submit in AHK

Tags: user-interface, autohotkey

So I bet the has already been covered but I couldn't find it, so if you know where the answer is, simply point me in the right direction! 
I have a GUI with two radio check boxes, and I would like to show/hide some commands based on which radio is selected. However, I would prefer not to have to create a new GUI, or have to click the Submit button to do so. Is there a way to trigger guicontrol without submitting the gui?
Thanks!
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out how to accomplish what I'm trying to do, and so I'm posting it here for posterity sake! ;)

I realized that I could use `GUI, Submit` without closing the form if I appended it with `nohide`. So I created a glabel for both radio buttons, so when either one is selected they activate a subroutine which submits the form (without hiding it), and does whatever actions I want it to, such as show more commands, or insert text.
Paul